# Changing ContentTemplate using DataTriggerBehavior in UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

I am trying to split out my `View` into multiple `UserControl`s and then display the appropriate `View` depending on a certain value.

I accomplish this in WPF like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CardView">
        <views:CardView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="OtherView">
        <views:OtherView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MainView">
        <views:MainView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

...

<ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MainView}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentView}" Value="Other">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource OtherView}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentView}" Value="Card">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CardView}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentView}" Value="Main">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MainView}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

This works great in WPF, and the `CurrentView` is a `string` property on the `ViewModel` that is changed via `Button` presses/etc.

Since there are no `DataTrigger`s in UWP, I have read that you can accomplish the same thing using `DataTriggerBehavior`s instead. So I have tried this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PaymentView">
        <local:PaymentView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="InvoiceView">
        <local:InvoiceView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

...

<ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource InvoiceView}"
                RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.Below="PageHeader">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentView}" Value="Invoice">
            <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource InvoiceView}" />
        </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentView}" Value="Payment">
            <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PaymentView}" />
        </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ContentControl>
```

But for some reason, the `ChangePropertyAction` is not firing. I know that the `CurrentView` is changing, as I have set a breakpoint on it. Just in case, here is the property:

```
private string _currentView;
public string CurrentView
{
    get { return _currentView; }
    set { Set(ref _currentView, value); }
}
```

I am using Template10, so all of my `ViewModel`s inherit `BindableBase` through `ViewModelBase`, so all the `OnPropertyChanged` stuff should also be working properly (all other properties are working fine).

Anyway, I know the `CurrentView` is changing, but the `ChangePropertyAction` behavior is not firing. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Is Viewmodel object is under the DataContext of ContentControl?

Comment: I assumed that it inherited it. I ended up changing the `Binding` to `{Binding CurrentView}` instead of the compiled binding `{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentView}` and now it works. I thought I had tried that already, but apparently not. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had assumed that the `ContentControl` would work using the compiled binding `{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentView}` because the designer recognized that binding with AutoComplete.

Once I changed it to use regular binding `{Binding CurrentView}`, then the trigger started working properly. Here is the working version:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PaymentView">
        <local:PaymentView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="InvoiceView">
        <local:InvoiceView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

...

<ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource InvoiceView}"
                RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.Below="PageHeader">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding CurrentView}" Value="Invoice">
            <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource InvoiceView}" />
        </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding CurrentView}" Value="Payment">
            <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PaymentView}" />
        </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Wish I had found this before I spent an hour or so trying to figure out why it wasn't working.